# Upgrade YAZ to YAZ 5

Tags: software-installation, shared-library, mono

I try to use [MarcEdit 6](http://marcedit.reeset.net/). If I use its tool "Z39.50/SRU Client" to search for any book in any offered library-database it doesn't work and I get the message

```
"Exception Information: Message: yaz4_64.dll
Source: Zoom.Net.YazSharp
Stack Trace: [...very long text...]"
```

MarcEdit 6 needs [YAZ 5](http://indexdata.com/yaz). I installed `yaz 4.2.30-2.1build1` which is the only version offered in Ubuntu Software Center - neither is there a version 5 nor any possibility to upgrade. Without knowing what I was doing I also did what is [recommended](http://ftp.indexdata.dk/pub/yaz/ubuntu/README) but I'm not sure if I did everything right and if I didn't, where I made a mistake. Maybe somebody can help me with this very specific question.

In the `linux_install.txt` file of MarcEdit 6 there is recommended:

> d) `Yaz.Sharp.dll.config` -- ensure that the `dllmap` points to the correct version of the shared `libyaz` object.

I have no idea what this means.

During the installation of MarcEdit 6 I did nothing exceptional (I unzipped the downloaded file, installed "mono" and executed MarcEditor via the terminal). During the installation of YAZ I first manipulated my sources.list file as recommended in the above README link and finally just got YAZ via the Software Center).

UPDATE:
I installed libyaz 5 (`sudo apt-get install libyaz5-dev`) and it's still the same problem when searching with the Z39.50 client.

I now also changed `Yaz.Sharp.dll.config` to version 5 (instead of before: `dll="yaz3.dll"`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <dllmap dll="yaz5.dll" target="libyaz.so" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: From what I can see MarcEdit is a Windows program, and thus includes its own copy of the yaz library (the yaz4_64.dll). However, it appears to be crashing for you when you try to do this. You need to report this as a bug to the MarcEdit developers. It seems to have nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @dobey I see a Linux download on their site (sorry I don't have a link, slow tablet here). The appearance of a dll is confusing however.  mischa004: please [edit]  your question to include more information about what version of marcedit you are using and how you installed it. Thanks.

Comment: Just before I go into details this short question: maybe it has got to do with the following information from the linux_install.txt-file? It says:"Yaz.Sharp.dll.config -- ensure that the dllmap points to the correct version of the shared libyaz object." I absolutely don't understand what this is saying, sorry.

Comment: @Seth Yes, it is a proprietary Windows application written in C#. It appears to be trying to use Windows DLLs. Maybe it's not meant to, but seems that asking support from the developers directly is appropriate, as it is a proprietary application.

Comment: @dobey Yes, asking the developer is appropriate, but I do not believe that is a good reason to shut them down here.

Comment: @mischa004 Sounds like useful information to include in your question.

Comment: Well a bug is a bug, and bug reports are off topic. If something claims to support Ubuntu, but doesn't actually run on it, then it's a bug in that thing. Released versions of Ubuntu aren't going to get new versions of libraries, like that. And it appears Ubuntu simply includes a straight copy of what's in Debian, for yaz. One could get it updated in Debian, and get it synced over for the next release of Ubuntu, but it's not likely to get released as an update to current stable releases of Ubuntu. Might be possible to get it into the _backports_ archive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you will see this now, but the config you want to use is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="yaz4_64.dll" target="libyaz.so.5" />
</configuration>
```

This works for me.

Comment: Note for version 6 ~ November 2017. The file to edit is now Zoom.Net.YazSharp.dll

Answer (score 0):

It works, the developer told me to change in the `Zoom.Net.YazSharp.dll.config` file the following:

```
dll="yaz4_64.dll" target="libyaz.so"
```

---

But the following problem occured and the developer has no solution (he wrote: "that’s not a file referenced in MarcEdit")

```
Exception Information:
Message: winhttp.dll
Source: mebatch
```